# Parsing JSON with PHP and CURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a problem with **JSON and PHP.**
Through CURL I query the API of a site and in response I have JSON.

When I give the command `var_dump (json_decode ($ result));` he does not print it well.
Where am I wrong?

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$url = "https://vulners.com/api/v3/audit/audit/?os=redhat&version=7.1&package=redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64";


$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));
$result = curl_exec($cURL);
var_dump(json_decode($result));
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
curl_close($cURL);
```

`?>`

**JSON:**

```
{ "result": "OK", "data": { "packages": { "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64": { "RHSA-2017:3108": [ { "package": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64", "providedVersion": "0:7.2-9.el7", "bulletinVersion": "7.2-9.el7_2.3", "providedPackage": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64", "bulletinPackage": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7_2.3.x86_64.rpm", "operator": "lt", "bulletinID": "RHSA-2017:3108", "cvelist": [], "fix": "sudo yum -y update redhat-release-server" } ], "RHSA-2017:1384": [ { "package": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64", "providedVersion": "0:7.2-9.el7", "bulletinVersion": "7.2-9.el7_2.2", "providedPackage": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64", "bulletinPackage": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7_2.2.x86_64.rpm", "operator": "lt", "bulletinID": "RHSA-2017:1384", "cvelist": [], "fix": "sudo yum -y update redhat-release-server" } ] } }, "vulnerabilities": [ "RHSA-2017:3108", "RHSA-2017:1384" ], "reasons": [ { "package": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64", "providedVersion": "0:7.2-9.el7", "bulletinVersion": "7.2-9.el7_2.3", "providedPackage": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64", "bulletinPackage": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7_2.3.x86_64.rpm", "operator": "lt", "bulletinID": "RHSA-2017:3108", "cvelist": [], "fix": "sudo yum -y update redhat-release-server" }, { "package": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64", "providedVersion": "0:7.2-9.el7", "bulletinVersion": "7.2-9.el7_2.2", "providedPackage": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64", "bulletinPackage": "redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7_2.2.x86_64.rpm", "operator": "lt", "bulletinID": "RHSA-2017:1384", "cvelist": [], "fix": "sudo yum -y update redhat-release-server" } ], "cvss": { "score": 0.0, "vector": "NONE" }, "cvelist": [], "cumulativeFix": "sudo yum -y update redhat-release-server", "id": "WAIT4O6XKXKD4SF9KIRJFJ2DG0J47R3DI1Y42J661KCJ5D0N9DB7TLB1E36N5OQ34JDB0PG1MP893WHTFL60YGQ92RJ3FC4JX7SLZNTUU5DTD3GLFK5PQJ5T1NYGVIBT" } }int(1) int(1)
```

**very well :)**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Comment: so what problem you are facing now? You have data.

Comment: What do you mean "*he does not print it well*"... ?!?

Answer (score 0):

The `int(1)` is the actual return value of the `curl_exec` command as the [documentation states](http://php.net/curl_exec):

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

Hence, you can try to set
`curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`
since this should return the response itselft on success.

Then use `var_dump(json_decode($result, true));` to get a pretty print.